# Get the sign, mantissa and exponent of a floating point number

Tags: c, floating-point, unions

I found this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

union foo
{
    struct float_guts
    {
        unsigned int fraction : 23;
        unsigned int exponent : 8;
        unsigned int sign     : 1;
    } fg;
    float f;
};

void print_float(float f)
{
    union foo ff;
    ff.f = f;
    printf("%f: %d 0x%X 0x%X\n", f, ff.fg.sign, ff.fg.exponent, ff.fg.fraction);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_float(0.25);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
0.250000: 0 0x7D 0x0
```

I have tried to understand as extract the sign, mantissa and exponent, but so far do not understand how

Can someone explain to me?

Comment: What output did you expect to get? What output do you actually get? What compiler, standard library and operating system are you using? What versions of those?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: the code works fine, I just want to understand how it does

Comment: What do you expect? Don't forget that the mantissa is effectively 24 bits, since the MS bit is an implied `1` (except for 0 value). The exponent has an offset too. Please read [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: You do know how the [IEEE floating point (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) format works? The union and the structure is simply another way to represent the format.

Comment: @Kevin is the question title incorrect? Should it be "How does a `union` work?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Can you explain how this method works, this code intrigues me

Comment: @Kevin you would be better researching unions and bitfields, since your code works, and this isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: @Weather Vane:  I will not be calm without knowing how it works, I want learn

Comment: The three bit fields in the `union` such as `unsigned int fraction : 23;` (these three bit field sizes add up to 32) allow the three parts of the `float` (also 32 bits) to be seen separately. I added the output of the program to your question, to show what they are. The links posted explain how `float` works better than I can.

Comment: thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand what IEEE-754 *Single-Precision* Floating Point format is. Simply put, it is the binary format in which floating point numbers are stored. For *32-bit* floating point numbers, it consists of a single *sign-bit* (1-negative), 8-bit exponent (in excess-127 notation), and 23-bit mantissa/significand (in hidden bit format). There are countless examples of how to convert to/from IEE754 notation, but suffice it to say it is the `1 + 8 + 23 = 32-bit` encoding used by your computer to store floating point numbers. For example, you `0.25` number is stored as:

```
(0.25 float - value in memory)
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
|s|      exp      |                  mantissa                   |
```

or `'s'`, `'exp'` and `'mantissa'` in hex format:

```
0  0x7d  0x0
```

The entire issue with the `union` has to do with the fact that and `integer` is also a `32-bit` value. So for every floating point values, there is an equivalent *integer representation* that can be derived from the same 32-bits above. (this of course brings in the issue of *endianess* of the hardware you are running on because the bits will be stored in memory differently)

Nevertheless, while not advisable for all the reasons in the comments and the answers, you can create a union between an `int`(unsigned) and `float` so you can satisfy yourself concerning the bits in memory. For example:

```
typedef union {
    float fv;
    unsigned int iv;
} ifu;
```

If you then create an instance of this `union` and assign your `0.25` as the floating point value, it will be stored in memory as shown above (assuming little-endian, etc..) e.g.:

```
ifu tmp;
tmp.fv = 0.25;
```

You can then look at those very same bits in memory as either a `float` (your `0.25` value) or as the equivalent unsigned integer value. A simple `printf` with `%u` or `0x%0x` will give you:

```
1048576000   0x3e800000 (in hex)
```

The bits are the very same, all you are doing is looking at different interpretations of the bits -- either as a float, or as an integer.

That, in a nutshell, is the IEEE-754 single precision floating point, sign bit, exponent, mantissa, unions, unsigned integer equivalent -- issue. The is much more to it than this, but this will provide a framework for you to understand the different topics.

Comment: Hmmm "223-bit mantissa"?  (typo).   Disagree with "integer is also a 32-bit".  OTOH, `uint32_t` is always 32-bit.

Comment: Agree on both points. Depending on the level of the question, I try and tailor the level of the answer to provide relevant information without further clouding or complicating the main issue with collateral detail. Sometimes I get the balance right, sometimes it leaves something to be desired. For purposes here, I should have added a note that we were presuming an int to be 32-bit for sake of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

> Get the sign, mantissa and exponent of a floating point number

Using a union depends on knowing format of a `float` and endian-ness, something not defined by C. OP's approach *may* somewhat work, it may not.  If using [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) OPs approach suffers from not taking into account exponent bias, [not-a-numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), sub-normal numbers, etc.

To get the sign;

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
bool sign = signbit(x);
```

To break a floating-point number into a normalized fraction and an
integral power of 2:

```
#include <math.h>
int exponent;
float fraction; // [0.5f to 1.0)
fraction = frexpf(x, &exponent);
```

Comment: Reasonable platforms use the same endian-ness for floating-point values and integers, because there are advantages to do so. The thing not defined by C and that can really go either way is the layout of bit-fields.

Answer (score 0):

The union makes the struct and the float share the same memory space.
The code writes the float member and then reads the other member of the union. It supposes that the float has a 23 bits mantissa, a 8 bits exponents and a sign bit, and prints those.

NB unions are for saving memory space, writing a member and reading another is undefined behavior - it might work on some systems or not on others. The float mapping is not very portable either.